# How to make the elements cover 100% of the space available in a container using Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 2 containers, and I'm trying to make them both have the same height. I'm using flexbox to solve this problem using the property `flex-direction: column (flex-column)` but I do not know what I'm doing wrong so that each element is divided by height of the available container.

[image]

```css
.borde_gris_b{
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row p-0 m-0 m-auto justify-content-center">
     <!-- first container-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xl-4 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">SNIES</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                <div class="card-text">12967</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Duración</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 10 periodos academicos </p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Número de Créditos</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 170 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Modalidad de Formación</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Presencial </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- two container-->
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 ">
        <div class="row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" >
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0" >

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 ">Becas</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                        <div class="d-flex mb-1">
                            <div class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </div>
                            <div>

                                <p > $2,107,000 </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Valor Matrícula</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> $5,696,000 </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
  
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Jornada</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```

I need both elements to have the same height, and that the elements present in each container are distributed by the available height of the container.

Comment: Note that you can likely recreate what you've done on jsFiddle here on Stack Overflow using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), and then people could more easily understand, and answer, your question without leaving this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem #1

> I need both elements to have the same height

The flexbox does not have `height: 100%` and does, therefore, not fill the full height of its parent container (which would be the same as the left column). 
So let's add this: Since you are using bootstrap already just add the `h-100` class to the marked element.

```
<!-- two container-->

<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 ">
  <div class="row p-0 m-0"> <!--=========THIS CONTAINER===========-->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

        <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
          <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 ">Becas</h6>
          <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
          <div class="d-flex mb-1">
            <div class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </div>
            <div>

              <p> $2,107,000 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

... more code
... more code
... more code
```

---

#### Problem #2

> the elements present in each container are distributed by the available height of the container.

For this you want to use the `flex` property, which is well described on w3schools.com ([click me](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)). Also notice the description of their first exmaple:

> Let all the flexible items be the same length, regardless of its content.

This is exactly what we want! So let's add this as well. Since you only used bootstrap and no custom classes it would be a nightmare to specify the path so let's just add a custom ID for it instead and add the CSS.

```
#second > div > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

At the end this is the final result:

```css
.borde_gris_b {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

#second>div>div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row p-0 m-0 m-auto justify-content-center">
  <!-- first container-->
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xl-4 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
      <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">SNIES</h6>
        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
        <div class="card-text">12967</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

      <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Duración</h6>
        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 10 periodos academicos </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

      <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Número de Créditos</h6>
        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 170 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

      <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Modalidad de Formación</h6>
        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Presencial </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- two container-->

  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 ">
    <div id="second" class="row p-0 m-0 h-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

          <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
            <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 ">Becas</h6>
            <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
            <div class="d-flex mb-1">
              <div class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </div>
              <div>

                <p> $2,107,000 </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

          <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
            <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Valor Matrícula</h6>
            <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> $5,696,000 </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

          <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
            <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Jornada</h6>
            <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end row -->
```

---

#### Edit #1

In this edit I explain the following comment:

> Thank you! It has become very clear. just one doubt. the property `flex :1` comes by default? I understood that putting `display: flex` makes all the elements have the same size (same result of `flex:1`,, I understand that)

As described on my provided link:

> The `flex` property is a shorthand property for:
>
> - `flex-grow`
> - `flex-shrink`
> - `flex-basis`.

The CSS syntax is: `flex: flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis|auto|initial|inherit;`
So in this case you could also just write `flex-grow: 1`.

`flex-grow` on the other hand is described like this:

> The `flex-grow` property specifies how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container.

So we even have a specific CSS attribute to accomplish your goal.

**But what does `display: flex` do and why isn't it enough?**

`display: flex` initializes the container as a flexbox with the **default values**. If `display: flex` would be enough to do the same as `flex-grow: 1` the default value for `flex-grow` should be `1`. However, the default value is `flex-grow: 0` and adding `display: flex` is, therefore, not enough.

Comment: Thank you! It has become very clear. just one doubt. the property flex :1 comes by default? I understood that putting display: flex makes all the elements have the same size (same result of flex:1,, I understand that).

Comment: I made an edit that (hopefully) explains it to you. I added some extra infos to make it more understandable. At the end it comes down to the fact that `display: flex` is initialized with default values. `flex-grow` has a default value of `0` and not `1`.

Comment: thanks!!! can you help me with this question?  I did it but not worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927717/the-property-flex1-does-not-serve-to-put-my-elements-of-the-same-size-to-cover

Comment: I think you already got some good answers. You should think about how you structure your code, how you use bootstrap and how much you should use bootstrap because I see over complicated code that would be so much more readable and simpler without bootstrap (or at least not as much).

Comment: Also if my answer answered your question (which it did if I understand you correctly) then don't forget to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you out:

```css
.borde_gris_b{
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row p-0 m-0 m-auto justify-content-center">
     <!-- first container-->
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-xl-4 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">SNIES</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                <div class="card-text">12967</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Duración</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 10 periodos academicos </p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Número de Créditos</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> 170 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

            <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Modalidad de Formación</h6>
                <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Presencial </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- two container-->
    
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0 m-0 ">
        <div class="row p-0 m-0" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 p-0 m-0  text-center p-0  d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
place-content: stretch space-between;
align-items: stretch;
max-width: 100%;">
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0" >

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 ">Becas</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "></p>
                        <div class="d-flex mb-1">
                            <div class="mr-3"> Beca Bien </div>
                            <div>

                                <p > $2,107,000 </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Valor Matrícula</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> $5,696,000 </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
  
                <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                    <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column  w-100">
                        <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 ">Jornada</h6>
                        <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 "> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end row -->
```