# the property flex:1 does not serve to put my elements of the same size to cover 100% of the height of the container

Tags: css

I have 2 containers and I intend that the elements of each container fit the full size of the container. I want to make one container look bigger than the other.

[image]

I use the property `flex: 1` and it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.borde_gris_b{
  border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}

.row{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="col-6 p-0 m-0  text-center">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="d-flex borde_gris_b m-0">
                <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column text-inherit w-100">
                    <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 font-weight-500">Valor Matrícula</h6>
                    <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 line-height-1"> $5,696,000 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
                <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column text-inherit w-100">
                    <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 font-weight-500">Jornada</h6>
                    <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 line-height-1"> Diurna/Nocturna </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-0 m-0 text-center" style="
    height: 100%;
">
        <div class="cardcustom d-flex flex-column" style="
    height: 100%;
">
            <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">
                <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column text-inherit w-100 p-3">
                    <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 font-weight-500">Contacto</h6>
                    <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 line-height-1"> fsdfs Valencia </p>
                    <div class="card-text" style="word-break: break-all;font-size: 13px;">
                        <span class="d-block"> fdsfs </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column text-inherit w-100">
                    <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0 font-weight-500">Facultad</h6>
                    <p class="card-text p-0 m-0 line-height-1"> Chgfh </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex  borde_gris_b m-0">

                <div class="h-100 flex-center flex-column text-inherit w-100">
                    <h6 class="p-0 mx-0 mb-1 mt-0">Modalidad de formación</h6>
                    <p class="card-text p-0 m-0"> Presencial </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note: I can have "n" number of elements**

Answer (score 0):

```
.d-flex.flex-column {
    height: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-column > .d-flex {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

row {
    align-items: center;
}
```

You might want to write your own selectors to target those elements. I'm not a fan of bootstrap, so I couldn't tell you if overwriting those classes is ok.

Comment: thanks but, with this change my elements are not centered vertically

Comment: @yavg Check it now! You could even drop that align-items: stretch; from the .flex-column. It is redundant

Answer (score 0):

The following demo has:

- Bootstrap v. 4.3.1 stylesheet loaded.
- simplified layout to recommended BS classes.

  - Hierarchy is `.container > .row > .col-md-6`
- tags are different types other than just `<div>` for semantics and readability.

  - Hierarchy is `main > div > article > section`.
- `.d-flex`, `.flex-column`, and `.flex-justify-center` are applied only to each `article.col-md-6` since they are the only tags that need their content stretched.
- the second `section` has [**`.flex-grow-1`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) assigned to it in order to stretch to the bottom of `article.col-md-6`.

Also as an option:

- if you want all of the text centered -- assign `.text-center` BS class to `div.row`
- if you want the last section of each column to stretch to the bottom and do not know how many columns you may have (added dynamically), place the following jQuery in a `<script>` tag (and ensure that `<script>` tag is after any `<script src="...">` tags but before the closing `</body>` tag).

  ```
  $('article.col-md-6 > section:last-of-type').addClass('flex-grow-1')
  ```

  Also, if you add any `section`s after page has loaded, add the statement as the last line of the function that adds the `section`s.

**Note: View in Full Page Mode**

```css
.row {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class='container'>
  <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
  
    <article class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-column flex-justify-center">
      <section class="pt-1 mb-2">
        <h5>Heisenberg</h5>
        <blockquote class='blockquote'>
          <p>I AM the danger! A guy opens his door and gets shot and you think that of me? No. I am the one who knocks!</p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
      <section class="pt-1 mb-2 flex-grow-1">
        <h5>Hank Schrader</h5>
        <blockquote class='blockquote'>
          <p>Lots of bodies apparently. Y'know even by Cartel standards. We'll know more when the buzzards leave the bones.</p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
    </article>

    <article class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-column flex-justify-center">
      <section class="pt-1 mb-2">
        <h5>Mike Ehrmantraut</h5>
        <blockquote class='blockquote'>
          <p>I promise you this, either we're all going home or none of us are. Now settle down. On your feet.</p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
      <section class="pt-1 mb-2">
        <h5>Saul Goodman</h5>
        <blockquote class='blockquote'>
          <p>Did you not plan for this contingency? I mean the Starship Enterprise had a self-destruct button. I'm just saying.</p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
      <section class="pt-1 mb-2">
        <h5>Tuco Salamanca</h5>
        <blockquote class='blockquote'>
          <p>I beat the piss out of your mule boy, and then you walk in here, and you bring me more meth? That's a brilliant plan, ese. Brilliant.</p>
        </blockquote>
      </section>
    </article>
    
  </div>
</main>
```